# Is Redis "Promiseable" in node?

Tags: node.js, redis, promise

It seems that different from another data repositories I am using, I can't use the following strategy in Redis:

```
  export class CollectPromises {
       private cachePromises: Array<Promise<any>> = [];

        public addPromise(promise: Promise<any>): void {
           this.cachePromises.push(promise);
        };

        public async executeAllPromises(): Promise<void> {
            await Promise.all(this.cachePromises);
        };
    };
```

My functions in Redis:

```
    async function addSingleDataToSet(key: string, data: any): Promise<boolean> {
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {


            RedisManager.redisClient.sadd([key].concat(data), ((err, res: number) => {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(res == 1);
                }
            }));
        });
    };

    async function usingRedis(x, y): Promise<void> {
        await addSingleDataToSet(x, y);
    }
```

And the actual code that should not fire anything before executeAllPromises() (as far as I understand and as it happens in others repositories)

```
CollectPromises.addPromise(usingRedis(x, y));
CollectPromises.addPromise(usingRedis(a, b));
CollectPromises.addPromise(usingRedis(c, d));
await CollectPromiser.executeAllPromises();
```

The problem is that CollectPromises.addPromise(usingRedis(x, y)) (same to the others) is fired before the executeAllPromises() which only happens using Redis.

I'd like to know wether I am doing something wrong or facing some specific Redis/Node issue.

Comment: *The problem is that CollectPromises.addPromise(usingRedis(x, y)) (same to the others) is fired before the executeAllPromises()*  - is this a problem? This is what Promise.all is for. If it doesn't do what you want then you likely don't need it. Please, clarify what is the desirable behaviour. Should Redis requests be made one after another? Also, CollectPromises is weird abstraction, it shouldn't exist, this can be done with plain JS. There are no promiseable or unpromiseable things. You're promisifying it correctly, if that's what you're asking. And there are promisified Redis packages.

Comment: The function fires when I push it to the array, before the await Promise.all

Comment: This is expected. You didn't explain why this is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Promises start running the moment you create them. In your example they will execute whether you call executeAllPromises or not.

You would probably benefit from introducing the concept of a `Task`, defined as a function that returns a promise. That way you can start them when needed.

To do this you would need to change `usingRedis` to look something like:

```
const usingRedis = (x, y) => () => addSingleDataToSet(x, y);
```

and `executeAllPromises` would need to be adjusted to run the tasks:

```
await Promise.all(this.cachePromises.map(task => task()));
```

And then rename Promise -> Task in a bunch of places.

Comment: But isn't this exactly what I am doing? The interesting point is that I use the same strategy to access google datastore, and it works as  expected.

Comment: It's not quite what you're doing, it's adding another function call before creating the promise. I'm not sure why it was working with the google datastore, possibly internally it was delaying the action. It's also possible I'm completely misunderstanding what you're trying to do.
I have also encountered some libraries that claim to use promises, but actually use a roll-your-own implementation that doesn't fire until a .then handler is added. Does google datastore give you promises natively or did you need to promisify them?

Comment: I promisified it, almost same way. But I do agree that the inside parameters of a promise are tested when you create it, what makes me think that the key could be the existence or not of IO that is considered on how the promise will behaviour. Maybe the Redis Client does not look as an IO operation to the node? I will check again my code, but as now, I think that I am doing the same with Datastore and even MySQL. I didn't know about tasks. Learning now, thanks

Comment: The truth is that it shouldn't matter if the promises start running immediately rather than once you call Promise.all on them. What is the 'bad thing' that is happening as a result of them running immediately?
Also note that `Task` is just a term I'm using, I'm not sure if it's common. I've heard the term 'Thunk' thrown around as well to describe an extra function wrapper around an action. If you want more things to look up.

Comment: Hmm, I think that is exact this, David. The existence of IO will make the promise at a whole only when you add await or Promise.all. Does it make sense to you? This hypothesis explains all the behaviour I am seeing now,

Comment: From node's point of view the existence of IO shouldn't affect anything. Native promises immediately call their describing function the moment you create them, not when you add awaits or .thens

Comment: David, let me explain the case. I open a database transaction, I run a lot of DML and operations in the datastore, for instance. The point is that if something gone wrong, I can rollback MYSQL, but can't rollback others non ACID databases. So I use some strategies to close the gap between the changes in non acid databases and the commit. When I commit the databases, I can put all the information in the caches at the same time, this reduced a lot consistency problems during system execution

Comment: function a(x): Promise<number>;  x = a(y); x will have a pending promise if there is IO, x = await a(y) will resolve the promise

Comment: david, thanks, the guides you gave me led me to the solution. Using Currying (https://hackernoon.com/currying-in-js-d9ddc64f162e), the problem was solved.